# Root finding using bisection method in Python

Tags: python, performance, algorithm

This code below is supposed to calculate the root of a function using bisection method. I am a newbie to Python, so  I do not know how to raise errors. Also, I would like to have a general review on this algorithm design, where I could have optimised, utilised some tricks or any sort of improvements. I feel like I am really not using the full funcionality of Python somehow.

Any comments on how to write a succinct code is appreciated. Thanks.

```
"""
Program to find root of a function using bisection method
"""
import sys
import math

def is_equal(a,b):
    return abs(b-a) < sys.float_info.epsilon

def bisection(f, a, b, TOL=0.01, MAX_ITER=100):
    """
    f is the cost function, [a,b] is the initial bracket, 
    TOL is tolerance, MAX_ITER is maximum iteration.
    """
    f_a = f(a)
    f_b = f(b)

    iter = 0
    while iter < MAX_ITER:
        c = (a+b)/2
        f_c = f(c)

        if math.isclose(f_c,0.0,abs_tol=1.0E-6) or abs(b-a)/2<TOL:
            return (c, iter)
        else:
            if f_a * f_c < 0:
                b = c
                f_b = f_c
            else:
                a = c
                f_a = f_c
            iter = iter + 1
    return None

def func(x):
    """
    The cost function: f(x) = cos(x) - x
    """
    return math.cos(x) - x

root, iter = bisection(func, -1, 1, TOL=1.0E-6)
print("Iteration = ", iter)
print("root = ", root, ", func(x) = ", func(root))
```

Answer (score 3, accepted):

### Type hints

They can help; an example:

```
def is_equal(a: float, b: float) -> bool:
```

The return type of `bisection` should probably be `Optional[float]`.

### Argument format

`MAX_ITER` and `TOL` should be lower-case because they are the arguments to a function, not a global constant.

### Early-return

```
        return (c, iter)
    else:
```

does not need the `else`, so you can drop it.

### In-place addition

```
        iter = iter + 1
```

can be

```
        iter += 1
```

### Return parens

This does not need parentheses:

```
        return (c, iter)
```

The tuple is implied.

Answer (score 3):

- I don't see the point of passing `MAX_ITER`. Bisection is guaranteed to terminate in \$\log \dfrac{b - a}{TOL}\$ iterations.
- I strongly advise against breaking the loop early at `math.isclose(f_c,0.0,abs_tol=1.0E-6)`. It only tells you that the value at `c` is close to `0`, but doesn't tell you *where* the root is (consider the case when the derivative at root is very small). After all, tolerance is passed for a reason!

  If you insist on early termination, at least return the `(a, b)` interval as well. The caller deserves to know the precision.
- You may want to do this test right before returning (like, is there a root at all):

  ```
  if math.isclose(f_c,0.0,abs_tol=1.0E-6):
      return None
  return c
  ```

  but I'd rather let the caller worry about that.
- `abs` in `abs(b - a)` seems excessive.

  ```
  if a > b:
      a, b = b, a
  ```

  at the very beginning of `bisection` takes care of it once and forever.
- `(a + b)` may overflow. `c = a + (b - a)/2` is more prudent.
- I don't see where `is_equal(a,b)` is ever used.